# listview - access to non-visible items

Tags: android, android-listview

I would like to check which of elements on my listview is also a member of another list and check all of them (by changing background). But the only way I can think of is:

```
for (String str : list1){
    if (list2.contains(str)) {
       lv.getChildAt(adapter.getPosition(str)).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
    }
}
```

But that works only for visible elements of the list and throws null pointer exception when accessing non-visible elements. What can I do to apply changes for all list items? Do I have to write my own adapter or maybe there is any "equivalent" of *getChiledAt* but working for all elements of the listview not only visible ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use onScroll method (as Chitrang suggested) and set everything only for visible item. Android Magic works, everything works fine, also for non-visible items :)

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
      for (int i = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i<=lv.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++){
            if (list2.contains(lv.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()))
                lv.getChildAt(i - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try by myself, but a suggestion. Can you please try this way, and check.

Idea is to use setOnScrollListener with onScroll method  and to have null check inside for loop.
It's not good solution though, because for loop working on every scroll.

```
        lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (String str : list1) {

                if (list2.contains(str)) {
                    if (lv.getChildAt(adapter.getPosition(str)) != null) {

                        lv.getChildAt(adapter.getPosition(str))
                                .setBackgroundColor(
                                        getResources()
                                                .getColor(
                                                        android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used onScroll method but a bit in other way. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `List`, with the (i assume you have) `id` like the `listview's` data.

Example :

You have class `Person` with `int id`, `String name`. Create a new `List<Integer>`  to store **all** (not just the visible one) of your `listview's` person id, normally by using the `listview's adapter`.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this solution. However it will be a bit complicated in my case - I would need a lot of such id lists, I would need to pass them between intents and I would need to remember which list is connected to which intent. I would prefer solution without additional lists...